# Mark as 2 if data exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables `tbl_Attendance` and `tbl_leave`. Values of these table shown like this.

**tbl_leave**:

```
id | empcode | Marked | datetime_From | datetime_To
1  | emp1    | 2      | 19-10-2018    | 22-10-2018
1  | emp2    | 2      | 20-10-2018    | 20-10-2018
```

**tbl_Attendance**:

```
id | empcode | Marked | datetime_
1  | emp1    | 1      | 20-10-2018
1  | emp2    | 1      | 20-10-2018
1  | emp3    | 1      | 20-10-2018
1  | emp4    | 1      | 20-10-2018
1  | emp5    | 1      | 20-10-2018
```

Now I want to change `tbl_Attendance` column `Marked` to 2 if exists in table `tbl_leave` like

**tbl_Attendance**

```
id | empcode | Marked | datetime_
1  | emp1    | 2      | 20-10-2018
1  | emp2    | 2      | 20-10-2018
1  | emp3    | 1      | 20-10-2018
1  | emp4    | 1      | 20-10-2018
1  | emp5    | 1      | 20-10-2018
```

Please someone help me

Answer (score 1):

This update query should solve your problem , please try it.

```
update tbl_Attendance set Marked=2 where empcode in (select empcode from tbl_leave)
```

If you want to update Marked in tbl_Attendance according to date in tbl_leave then you can try this query:

```
update tbl_Attendance set Marked=2 where empcode in 
(SELECT t.empcode from 
(SELECT TL.empcode,TA.datetime_,TL.datetime_From,TL.datetime_To from 
tbl_leave TL 
INNER JOIN tbl_attendance TA ON TL.empCode=TA.empcode) t
where t.datetime_ BETWEEN t.datetime_From and t.datetime_To)
```

The above query will update marked as 2 if dateTime_ in tbl_Attendance is between  dateTime_From and dateTime_To in tbl_Leave.

Comment: Please check the answer  i have edited it according to date.